# GTKをgladeでデザインした場合のライセンスについて

Tags: gcc, ライセンス, gpl, gtk

現在、LINUX OS上でGUIアプリの作成を考えているのですが
GTK上で gladeを使用してデザインし、
アプリ部分はC++(gcc)でコンパイルしようとしています

LINUXの開発自体初めてなので情報をこれから集めるのですが
Glade自体はGPLライセンスで作成アプリのようですがソースの公開は必要になるのでしょうか

gcc自体はコンパイルしたアプリの公開は必要ないようですが
どちらが適用されるのでしょう

Comment: これらが関連しているのでは？ [自由でないプログラムを開発するために、GNU EmacsのようなGPLの及ぶエディタを使っても良いでしょうか? GCCのようなGPLの及ぶツールを使って自由でないプログラムをコンパイルすることはできますか?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF), [GPLプログラムの出力結果もGPLが及ぶのは、どんな場合ですか?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL), 影響がある可能性はこれでしょう。[ライブラリが(LGPLではなく)GPLのもとでリリースされている場合、そのライブラリを利用するプログラムはGPLでなければならないのでしょうか?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.ja.html#IfLibraryIsGPL)

Comment: 原本がどこに有るのかわかりませんでしたが、Glade FAQ ((c)Damon Chaplin) というドキュメントに["Do I have to use a particular license for the C code generated by Glade?"](http://web.mit.edu/outland/share/gnome/help/glade/C/faq/index.html#AEN43)という節があるようです。

Comment: お二人ともありがとうございます。
公開する必要は無いけど、出来れば公開して欲しいということみたいですね。